# Create menu item

Tags: cocoa, interface-builder

I installed Xcode 9 and I'm trying to create menu items for my MacOS app.

I have no problems in Xcode 8:

1. Create method
2. Add method to First Responder
3. Add new item to the menu
4. Drag item to first responder a select method

I'm doing the same in Xcode 9 but the item is always disabled.

Comment: Which object implements the method? Is this object in the responder chain?

Comment: Hi @matt here is the project https://github.com/orange3000/PruebaMenu_9_2.git

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Swift 4, methods you create are not visible to Objective-C / Cocoa by default. Change

```
func pruebaBoton(_ sender: Any) {
```

to

```
@objc func pruebaBoton(_ sender: Any) {
```